# How can I fetch record in dropdown in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, mongodb, edit

I have edit profile page in my project.

In my edit page file

```
@foreach($userProfile as $profile)
@if($userId == $profile->id)
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-12">First Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstName" class="form-control form-control-line" value="{{$profile->personal_detail['first_name']}}" required>
      </div>
  </div>

<label class="col-md-12">Department</label>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <select class="custom-select form-control col-md-11" id="department" name="department">
      @foreach($listDepartment as $departmentList) 
        {
           <option value='{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}'>{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}</option>
        }
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
@endif
@endforeach
```

See In first name i write code in value=" " tag so it fetch first name from database and display me. How can i do same in dropdown?

In my database collection name is users

```
   "role_id" : "5c8a51ed650fbd5398503044",
    "username" : "Neel",
    "company_email" : "asd@abc.com"
    "personal_detail" : {
        "emp_id" : "101",
        "first_name" : "Abc",
        "middle_name" : "D",
        "last_name" : "Efg",
        "gender" : "Male",
        "city" : "USA",
        "state" : "HY",
        "department" : "Laravel",
        "designation" : "Junior Laravel Developer",
        "total_experience" : null,
        "about_me" : null
    },
```

Comment: You have already done in department dropdown. What exactly you want to do ?

Comment: In department My 1st record is laravel, while in my employee's department is HR so i want to fetch HR not laravel

Comment: do you have relationship between table? @John_rees

Comment: I am using mongoDb, But in my user table department field exist already

Comment: Could you please show your db structure. From where you want to fetch record

Comment: Ya sure, I update in question

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest to use record id for value in the options.
The simple (but not necessarily the best) way is to check the current value with `if`. With current code something like this:

```
<option value='{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}' @if($profile->nameOfDepartment == $departmentList->nameOfDepartment) selected @endif>{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}</option>
```

With id (suppose you have a `department_id` in each profile record):

```
<option value='{{$departmentList->id }}' @if($profile->department_id == $departmentList->id) selected @endif>{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}</option>
```

Comment: Nope , this not work man, In this record my department of that employee in HR and my department collection first record is Laravel So it displays me laravel,

Instead of laravel I want to fetch HR because, during add employee form i inserted HR in department

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
<select name="" id="" class="form-control">
      <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select</option>
      @foreach($listDepartment as $departmentList)
              <option {{ isset($departmentList->id) && $departmentList->id == $profile->id ? 'selected="selected"':'' }} value="{{$departmentList->id}}">{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}
             </option>      
      @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Actually it works but it's unable to fetch record from database